# In tosca what if What if not able to identify control unique in Tosca using Technical proprty,index,image and anchor not working

Tags: tosca

What if not able to identify control unique in Tosca using Technical proprty,index,image and anchor is there any other way to identify control unique?

Comment: can you add an example? At least image or indes or relative position should work

Comment: use constraints and explicit name

Answer (score 0):

Create a relative xpaths which can uniquely identity the element. For that we need to have proper skills to create quality xpaths which remains stable with time. Once created, the xpath can be explicitly added in the properties section of the module.